# Bootstrap footer element position bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Within a HTML page I have made, I wanted to add a footer. I am making use of Bootstrap and in [this example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) it is shown that the footer element can be positioned to the bottom of the page without putting the footer element inside a container element (directly within the body element, below a container element).

Whenever I try this myself, it looks like the element will be positioned to the bottom at first. But then I noticed on other pages (which were longer on content), the footer started appearing to the bottom of the browser instead of the body element. The effect is that the container element above the footer will show itself behind the footer and below without the footer going to the bottom of the body element.

**Make sure to scroll in the following example of code I made:**

```css
.body {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: tomato;
  /*The height is set so that an overflow: scroll; can happen, to reproduce
  my sitation. When the content of the body tag is too long, the browser will
  show a scroll bar and when scrolling down, the footer does not appear on the
  bottom anymore but somewhere in the middle or maybe even top side, depending on
  how long the body would become. */
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  /*This would be a dynamic number, when removing this property.
  If you do not really understand the idea I am talking about, try to change
  this value and see for yourself what happens (with the footer element).
  The height is set only for the sake of showing the issue. */
  height: 500px;
}
footer {
  background: #e0f2f7;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <h2>
    Foo
  </h2>
  <div class="container">
    asdasds
  </div>
  <footer>sadasdsa</footer>
</div>
```

What can I do to make my footer element behave just like the one in the [Bootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) (so that it will always stick to the bottom) and without having to put the footer element in a certain container element?

Answer (score 1):

If you want footer to be visible all the time at the bottom of the site, but not over the container. You need to add min-height:100% & position:relative to html not to body. To body element you need to add margin-bottom with value of footer height.

```css
html{
    min-height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    background-color: tomato;
    margin:0 0 60px 0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 300px;
}
footer {
    background: #e0f2f7;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:60px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Foo</h2>
        <div class="container">asdasds</div>
        <footer>sadasdsa</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1:**

If you want to make dynamic height of the footer use this JS code (if you use jQuery)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var height = $( 'footer' ).height();
    $( 'body' ).css('margin-bottom',height + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Is it also possible without the fixed margin-bottom? Since it's a footer, content might change and thus so should height. That would only cause another issue I think.

Comment: If you want dynamic height of footer I think it will require Javascript to do that.

Comment: What do you mean, can you refer me what you are thinking about? Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I edited the answer. Remove margin-bottom from body & height from footer. Than use the JS code. It will add margin-bottom to body depending on the footer content height.

Comment: I see what you are trying and it is not a bad way of handling this issue I guess. I think you have to make sure to remove the margin on the body selector in the css sheet with this code (or at least it is not necessary to leave it there)?

Comment: You can leave it there. JS will overwrite it. So basically the value from css should be closest to expected height (maybe average?) of footer to avoid jumps and other glitches.

Comment: I can see this would be working, but it would look very similar as just using a container element instead. I still wonder how this would work in Bootstrap. I noticed they use a fixed height in the example, but it is not necessary to use one (I tried removing it in the example and it did not cause any issues, even when resizing the container element above the footer, did not cause any trouble).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, below is your desired result?

It's because you set the height of the body to 300px; Resulting in a footer at 300px from the top. Remove that line and it should be fine.

```css
.body {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  /*This would be a dynamic number, when removing this property.
  If you do not really understand the idea I am talking about, try to change
  this value and see for yourself what happens (with the footer element).
  The height is set only for the sake of showing the issue. */
  height: 500px;
}
footer {
  background: #e0f2f7;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <h2>
    Foo
  </h2>
  <div class="container">
    asdasds
  </div>
  <footer>sadasdsa</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: If you remove the height property from my example, the idea of the overflow would not work. Basically I have a body element containing so much content that the browser shows a (or the) scrolling bar, causing a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Footer at bottom</title>
  <style>
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="footer">This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the way u can always keep the footer at the bottom of page

Comment: I have the exact same code in my example. The additional code is to reproduce my issue (when the page that needs to be shown, is longer than the browser screen, a scroll bar appears. After scrolling, the footer won't be at the bottom anymore).

Comment: when the content of the page will exceed the height of browser screen, then offcourse will have to scroll down to see the bottom of page. Footer will remain at the bottom of page.

Comment: The div tag containing the body class is there to represent the body and thus representing what happens. Footer does not stay at the bottom, that is why i made this question. https://jsfiddle.net/zwwdngcf/

Comment: If footer does not stay at the bottom in your page. Add more properties which are in my code. Then see, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using the class "navbar-fixed-bottom" on nav element. Try this example. To know how it works you can checkout this page - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-navbar.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Fixed Navbar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        padding-bottom: 70px;
    }
</style>
</head> 
<body>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <p style="line-height: 100px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.Quis quam ut magna consequat faucibus. Pellentesque eget nisi a mi suscipit tincidunt. Ut tempus dictum risus. Pellentesque viverra sagittis quam at mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio. Phasellus auctor velit at lacus blandit, commodo iaculis justo viverra. Etiam vitae est arcu. Mauris vel congue dolor. Aliquam eget mi mi. Fusce quam tortor, commodo ac dui quis, bibendum viverra erat. Maecenas mattis lectus enim, quis tincidunt dui molestie euismod. Curabitur et diam tristique, accumsan nunc eu, hendrerit tellus. Tibulum consectetur scelerisque lacus, ac fermentum lorem convallis sed.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know it's not about a navigation element...? Sure you could use classes for situations they are not intended though, but your example contains too much of the navigation HTML.