# sticky footer problems when footer is inside other div block

Tags: html, css, footer

I have problem with sticking footer to bottom of viewport.
I try different approaches, 
read footer topics here, read stickyfooter site, try and no luck, google too much, so the problem code I cut form my site can be tested out there:
https://jsfiddle.net/26hf8sh2/

the structure is

```
<html>
<body>
<root>
<header> ... </header>
<main> ... </main>
<footer> ... </footer>
</root>
</body>
</html>
```

I wish to expand main block to fit footer if there is no much content, and stick footer to bottom of viewport if again content is low, when I try absolute positioning footer overlaps content when i change browser size.
Also if I try something like min heights or so, then where there is lots of contents footer seems to overlap content and positionin at bottom of viewport but not at the bottom of page height.
So now I just add the min-height 800px and relative positioning. 
So if resolution of screen is about 1200px in height, then it looks normal, but when I open it on mobile, or change mode to full screen, I see gap at the bottom. I try to code my site, so you can see the problem for example in page protasov.by/contacts

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check my answer here [Sticky footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216929/bootstrap-footer-element-position-bottom/36217442#36217442)

Comment: I have change my website code, now seems to work, except 100% is seems too much, footer get down under page at a half, seems like to header 100px height, so should I somehow change some margin-top to make it slightly upper? Problems seems only where is low content, if page has much content then footer place is ok. So if I up footer then on big pages it can overlap content...

Comment: Seems if in page alot of content footer overlaps it, look at http://protasov.by/service/ page.

Comment: Change css. For html tag there should be min-height:100%. It will fix it.

Comment: Ok now seems to work in IE and Safari, but footer is under page. Is it possible to make it go up with relative position? the root div changes footer width and margins, so changing to absolute positioning cause to add properties manually and some problems with long pages. Аdding margin to html element make footer go more else down

Comment: So you don't want sticky footer? Sticky footer is footer which sticks to browsers bottom bar when there is a little content, but when there is more content it goes down with it. If you want it below content remove height:100% from html tag and make your footer relative. Why you have height:100% on so many tags in your css?

Comment: I want to stick it to bottom of viewport if there is less content or, make it go down with content if there is alot of content, but not under viewport height :) Or I'm get the idea wrong? Also min-height doesn't work in Chrome somewhy footer overlap content at page protasov.by/service

Comment: remove height:100%

Comment: Thanks, this height 100% is in main block cause this problem. Thanks alot with a half way to fixing footer :) Now the last thing is how to make it at the bottom of browser bar on pages with less content.

Comment: I added reply to question. Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Lets try something like this:

```
html{
    min-height:100%
}
body{
    min-height:100%
}
.root{
    position:relative;
}
footer{
    position:absolute; bottom:0;
}
.wb_main{
    margin-bottom:220px;
}
```

Comment: What is `position: bottom` ?

Comment: should be bottom:0.. too fast

Comment: Well with this code i use padding instead of margin in main block to save background of main block, but on short pages footer is sticked but there is a gap between main block and footer, height and min height didnt do anything with that, so guess should be workaround that stretch main block to footer if page is short with empty content :) possible?

Comment: on the site footer is still relative. If you set it absolute it will be fine. Just remove background from the footer, because you will have it already from wb_main.

Comment: I mean empty gap that noticeable because main block use background color and this gap is simply empty space that shows backgound image.

Comment: ok.. i see where is problem.. .wb_footer in line 725 - replace relative with absolute. .wb_main{padding-bottom: 220px;} .root{position:relative}

Comment: I modify code, so you can see the gap just go to tab number four inside of http://protasov.by/service/ page

Comment: also protasov.by/contacts shows same problem, seems like main block dint't stretch to footer

Comment: You can move background to .root class and move header out of .root with absolute out of the .root. In your place i would change that html to <header><div .root><footer>

Comment: guess that fills the header with bg color, margins and width from root also should go to body, then also gradient in footer is lost, so guess leave it with relative positioning :/ and get back to it soon.

Comment: Anyway thanks for pointing, I also thinking maybe make footer inside of main block maybe it will fix it positioning. will try later but main bg will meged with footer bg gradient, so to avoid that i guess probably use margin with foter height and change footer top to that margin but is margin goues like 100% height+margin height, how to put it inside that is the question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply to use calc function for min height in main block.
I just add:

```
   min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 320px);
   min-height: -o-calc(100% - 320px);
   min-height: -moz-calc(50% - 320px); /* Firefox 4+ */
   min-height: calc(100% - 320px);
```

100 px is header size and 220 is footer size.
So in short pages Footer get at the bottom of viewport

Comment: Somebody know why this works in chrome and safari and didn't in IE11? looks like problem with min-height in IE

Comment: well fixed for IE by change % to vh and adding min-height and height to html,body { * } with !important tag.